# When does Puzzling get its own Logo and Colour - What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, design

I see that many SE sites have their own logo and unique colour and the others don't.  I assumed it may be because those with an icon are out of Beta, but I was wrong, sites like [Craft CMS Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) already have a logo.

My question is, is it an action that the community can do on its own or does it require some sort of a voting or approval from the parent meta?  And if its within the community, what is the process to be followed?

Edit: [This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) this effectively answers some part of this question, so let's take this as

"What should our logo and site design look like?"

Comment: what should our logo be?

Comment: ;) thats an entirely different question, personally I would love some sort of a puzzle in it, however rather than boring ?? we could let our community drive the process if that is ok within the framework of things

Comment: Mostly likely a puzzle-piece with a stylised question mark or something

Comment: yes for the puzzle piece definitely (thats my opinion), but can we do better than stylised question mark?

Comment: I think it should be like a jigsaw puzzle with a piece taken out (the picture it makes could be a '?') it'd only be small, like a 9 piece puzzle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puzzling has its own provisional logo — the `??` icon. The rest will come when (if) the site graduates. CraftCMS is one of the very few beta sites with color in its provisional logo; normally the logo uses the beta colors. Puzzling is one of the few sites where the provisional logo is not the initials of the site.

The “7 essential meta questions of every beta” blog post is obsolete. Read [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta) instead. At the time, there was a vague idea that the design of the site would be community-sourced. Now Stack Exchange employs a professional designer, so discussing design ideas (which would only matter in months or years anyway) is pretty much pointless.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, but given the area 51 status, and the rate at which we have activity, do you feel we are really years away from or many months away from graduating?

Comment: @skv The criteria for graduation are a bit mysterious. It is know that the indications on Area 51 don't tell the whole story by far. Even then you can check the [launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) tab to compare stats with graduates sites; Puzzling has ⅓ as many questions as the latest gradaute [Salesforce](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce) did, barely any user with 3k rep, … In addition we're still struggling to produce quality content; that's a non-numeric criterion.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That last part is something I would agree with too, perhaps  that's worth discussing as a separate question

Answer (score 10):

Some impossible geometry might be nice, it's pretty and makes the user "puzzle" over it (also draws attention). Plus stuff like this looks like it's dying to be made into a logo.

[image]