# Should we consider adding links in spoiler tags?

Tags: discussion

I view my profile and questions with my iPad, and have to tap on the spoiler to reveal the answer. Whenever the answer contains a link to some site, and when I tap on it (since I don't know where the link is), the link opens up and I don't get the chance to see the answer. And it is really annoying.

Can we do something about it? Like a warning before the spoiler that it contains a link or something like that?

Comment: When you click to reveal a spoiler, you don't expect to be redirected, like I just did on this answer: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/35120/9802

Answer (score 1):

I think this springs from the [general overuse of spoiler markup on the site](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1498/spoiler-markup).

The link almost certainly shouldn't be hidden in the first place. You have to follow the link to discover the information it represents. **There isn't any danger of someone being "spoiled"** on the puzzle just by reading the link's name.

(In the rare case where the contents of the URL itself contain some hint, it's trivial to hide that with link markup: `[This writeup discusses the relevant mathematics.](http://example.com/wiki/Name_of_concept_which_is_key_to_solution)`. This is almost always preferable to a bare URL *anyways*.)

What we should do to fix the problem you're having, then, is simply to stop putting links in spoiler boxes.

Comment: I agree with you. And I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one facing this problem. I don't even know if it is a problem. It is just very annoying. And if we want to implement something like this, then this question should get a lot of attention.