# Should the tag alphametic require working by deault

Tags: discussion, tags, answer-quality

I think that maybe the alphametic tag should imply that working is required in the answer.

For example https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31354/16717 was accepted as the correct answer after others proved that there were not multiple solutions*.

Maybe the tag should even imply no-computers, although there may be *very* large space problems which could be interesting to solve by coding (I mean ones that are too big to simply traverse permutations, like the code I provided for further evidence in [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31355/16717)).

* the OP thought there were multiple solutions since the puzzle book it originated from stated such. I cannot read Russian so cannot confirm from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRIL8.jpg) if there is more to it than plain alphametics

Answer (score 3):

This is [already site policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-aggressively-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation), actually!

All answers need to provide some explanation for why that's the correct answer. If they don't, and the author doesn't add one, they can absolutely be deleted. Please flag 'em and/or (preferably and) leave a comment.

I've left a comment there, and will follow up in a bit.